# Grouping Data and maintaing Calculated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have few fields like Department, WorkLocation, Employees and Work Date
Need to  get the output based on the Given Date Parameter

```
Department  WorkLocation  EmployeeID   WorkDate
----------  ------------  ----------   --------
D1           L2            121          05/01/2018
D1           L1            141          05/01/2018
D2           L1            151          05/02/2018
and so on
```

I have tried using temp tables to store data and get from there but is not working

Department , Number of Employees worked on the given date,Number of Employees worked in Last 7 days from the given Date,Number of Employees worked from the Begining of Month to the Given Date
i.e

```
Department   WorkLocation     Count_On_Date   Count_Last7Days   Count_MonthToDate
----------    -----------     ------------    ---------------   -----------------
D1           L1              xxx                  xxx             xxx
D2           L1              xxx                  xxx             xxx
D1           L2              xxx                  xxx             xxx
D2           L2              xxx                  xxx             xxx
```

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: What you've got so far? Also consider filling these xxx with something. Should make it easier to understand what you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause and do the *conditional* aggregation with `case` expression

```
select Department, WorkLocation,
       sum(case when WorkDate = @givendate then 1 else 0 end) as Count_On_Date,
       sum(case when WorkDate >= dateadd(day, -8, @givendate) and 
                     WorkDate < @givendate
                then 1 else 0 end) as Count_Last7Days,
       sum(case when month(WorkDate) = month(@givendate) 
                then 1 else 0 end) as Count_MonthToDate
from table t
group by Department, WorkLocation;
```

Comment: This Worked... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This I tested, works like expected. You need to use inline counts with different criteria. To produce each line we have `case` clauses with one-way conditions to cancel out the unwanted values.

```
select 
    wd.Department, 
    wd.WorkLocation,
    COUNT(1) as Count_On_Date,
    COUNT(case when DATEDIFF(DAY, wd.WorkDate, GETDATE()) < 7 then 1 end) as Count_Last7Days,
    COUNT(case when DATEDIFF(DAY, wd.WorkDate, GETDATE()) < 30 then 1 end) as Count_MonthToDate
from WorkData as wd
group by wd.Department, wd.WorkLocation
```